# How to use for loops and Arrays in Python?

Tags: python

I need to print in python the child with the oldest name here is my code

```
def getSomeName():
nameArray = []
ageArray = []
school = input("What is the name of your new school? ")
nopupils = int(input('How many pupils in your new school? ')) + 1              
for i in range(1,nopupils):
    anyName = input('What is your name? ')
    nameArray.append(anyName)
    anyAge = int(input('What is your Age? '))
    ageArray.append(anyAge)
print(school)
topno = 0
for i in ageArray:
    if(i > topno):
        topno = i
        finalname = nameArray[i]            
print(finalname)
print(topno)


getSomeName()
```

My Problem is that it says I cant do `finalname = nameArray[i]`. 
 Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: send the error itself

Comment: I think that this is a homework problem and the instructor want you to look at the `max` function.

Comment: If this is a homework problem, be honest about it if you don't want to get closed down.

Comment: When you say `for i in ageArray`, each value of `i` will be an age, so it doesn't make sense to use that as an index value of another list.  Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the two lists by index.

Comment: those are not arrays, those are *lists*

Answer (score 1):

Use max to find the max age then find its index in the age list and then the associated name:

```
print( nameArray[ageArray.index(max(ageArray))] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is wrong. 'i' is equal to the age so you set topno to the largest age but then try to use that same age value for the index. Try using enumerate:

```
for index, i in enumerate(ageArray):
    if(i > topno):
        topno = i
        finalname = nameArray[index]            
print(finalname)
print(topno)
```

Answer (score 0):

for loops don't work like that in Python. Writing

```
for x in list:
    do x
```

you get the actual value, the user input, not the index.
So, this would work:

```
for i, item in enumerate(list):
    do x
```